# Como não exibir valores nulos e exibir valores em uma linha nesta condição?

Tags: postgresql

Tenho 3 tabelas, uma chama-se **custom_values** com um campo `VALUE` do tipo `TEXT` onde recebe diversos tipos de informações, logo eu identifico cada valor pelo relacionamento com outra tabela chamada **custom_fields** onde utilizo dois `ID's` para encontrar os `VALUES` que eu preciso e uma terceira tabela chamada **issues** que é relacionada com a **custom_values**.

---

### **Exemplo:**

```
.---------------------------------.    .------------------.
|          CUSTOM_VALUES          |    |      ISSUES      |
|---------------------------------|    |------------------|
|  ID | CF_ID | ISSUE_ID | VALUE  |    |  ID | START_DATE |              
|---------------------------------|    |------------------|
| 231 |  489  |    93    |     5  |    |  93 | 2016-10-11 |
| 322 |  502  |    93    |  0.25  |    |  94 | 2016-10-11 |
| 434 |  489  |    94    |     9  |    |  95 | 2016-10-11 |
| 234 |  489  |    95    |     5  |    |  96 | 2016-10-11 |
| 322 |  502  |    95    |  0.25  |    |  97 | 2016-10-13 |
| 243 |  489  |    96    |     7  |    |  98 | 2016-10-13 |
| 325 |  502  |    96    |  0.25  |    |  99 | 2016-10-15 |
| 352 |  489  |    97    |     8  |    | 100 | 2016-10-16 |
| 215 |  502  |    97    |   0.5  |    | 101 | 2016-10-16 |
'---------------------------------'    '------------------'

.------------------------------.
|        CUSTOM_FIELDS         |
|------------------------------|
|  ID |      DESCRICAO         |
|------------------------------|
| 489 | Funcionários Treinados |
| 502 | Duração Treinamento    |
'------------------------------'
```

---

Estou fazendo um `select` assim:

```
SELECT issues.id AS id, 
       CASE WHEN custom_fields.id = 489 
            THEN custom_values.value END AS funcionarios_treinados,
       CASE WHEN custom_fields.id = 502 
            THEN custom_values.value END AS duracao_treinamento, 
       start_date
  FROM issues
  LEFT JOIN custom_values on issues.id = custom_values.issue_id
  LEFT JOIN custom_fields on custom_fields.id = custom_values.cf_id
 WHERE custom_values.value <> '' AND custom_fields.id IN (489, 502)
 GROUP BY issues.id, custom_fields.id, custom_values.value, start_date
 ORDER BY start_date
```

Que retorna essa saída:

```
.----------------------------------------------------------------.
| id | funcionarios_treinados | duracao_treinamento | start_date |
|----|------------------------|---------------------|------------|
| 94 |           9            |                     | 2016-10-11 |
| 93 |           5            |                     | 2016-10-11 |
| 93 |                        |         0.25        | 2016-10-11 |
| 95 |           5            |                     | 2016-10-11 |
| 95 |                        |         0.25        | 2016-10-11 |
| 96 |           7            |                     | 2016-10-11 |
| 96 |                        |         0.25        | 2016-10-11 |
| 97 |           8            |                     | 2016-10-13 |
| 97 |                        |          0.5        | 2016-10-13 |
'----------------------------------------------------------------'
```

---

1 - Como faço para exibir somente os valores dos `funcionarios_treinados` e a `duracao_treinamento` que não sejam nulos?

2 - Como faço para exibir os valores em uma linha somente, pois quando comparo com o `CASE WHEN` o `custom_field.id` ele exibe cada `custom_values.value` em cada linha, mesmo que eles permaneçam ao mesmo `issue_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa seria utilizar `WITH` para cada tipo de registros e depois realizar uma consulta entre eles.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fd98d/16

```
with funcionario_treinado as (
    select
        issues.id as id,
        custom_values.value funcionarios_treinados,
        start_date
    from
        issues
    left join custom_values on issues.id = custom_values.issue_id
    left join custom_fields on custom_fields.id = custom_values.cf_id
where
    custom_values.value <> ''
    and custom_fields.id = 489
group by
    issues.id,
    custom_fields.id,
    custom_values.value,
    start_date),
duracao_treinamento as (
    select
        issues.id as id,
        custom_values.value duracao,
        start_date
    from
        issues
    left join custom_values on issues.id = custom_values.issue_id
    left join custom_fields on custom_fields.id = custom_values.cf_id
where
    custom_values.value <> ''
    and custom_fields.id = 502
group by
    issues.id,
    custom_fields.id,
    custom_values.value,
    start_date
)
select
    f.id,
    f.funcionarios_treinados,
    d.duracao,
    f.start_date
from
    funcionario_treinado f
    left join duracao_treinamento d on (f.id = d.id)
where 
    f.funcionarios_treinados IS NOT NULL AND d.duracao IS NOT NULL
order by
    f.start_date;
```

Comment: Perfeito, e adicionando a cláusula `where f.funcionarios_treinados IS NOT NULL AND d.duracao IS NOT NULL` responde as duas perguntas que eu fiz!
Obrigado Camilo!!